# Connecting to Acumatica with Auth0

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0, acumatica, auth0, openid-connect

When I try to connect to Acumatica with Auth0 OIDC using Vb.Net in Visual Studio 2017, I get the following error:

[image: ![enter image description here]

This doesn't appear to be related to the default browser on the system, as updating/changing the default browser doesn't help (not that I expected it to, as the User Agent string listed in the error doesn't look familiar). I'm left to assume that it has something to do with how Auth0 or Visual Studio itself is configured, and I can't get in to the code in Auth0 that creates it to see what is going on.

Is there any way I can see what control is actually being used for this in case there is some configuration that needs to be changed? What can I do to get this connecting properly?

EDIT:

The code I am running to get this is:

```
Dim client as New Auth0.OidcClient.Auth0Client(New Auth0.OidcClient.Auth0ClientOptions With {
                                               .Domain = "try.Acumatica.com/isv/identity",
                                               .ClientId = ClientIDFromConnectedApplications
                                               .RedirectUri = MyCompanysWebsite
                                               .Scope = "api offline_access"})
m_result = Await (client.LoginAsync)
```

Answer (score 0):

This really looks to be coming from VS itself. Notice the "User Agent" line? Lists all sorts of outdated tech as the User Agent being used. Maybe update your .NET version?

Comment: I'm on 4.5.2. You think upping it to 4.6.1 will make a difference?

Comment: Screenshot is from an embedded browser. You might want to look into forcing it to another User Agent. Perhaps this could help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dfa72b43-4004-47f9-84da-84f42cb77992/change-visual-studios-internal-browser-from-ie-to-chrome-or-firefox?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA: Unfortunately, that link only appears to contain suggestions that are later revealed to not work.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA: Your profile says you are a programmer at Acumatica. Is there any way to get any actual help from Acumatica?

Comment: Sure, DEV support is available as a billable service for VARs of all levels and we also offer direct customer support with or without VAR involved through SOW. Unlimited DEV support is available to ADN subscriber (level 2 and 3) and for premier customers. The only free option is from Acumatica Developer Community at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The question I have is why are you not trying to connect to the Acumatica web service/contract based API with a standard way that Acumatica suggests in their API documentation?  It looks like no one is using this Auth mechanism to connect to Acumatica API so far. You can refer to the API documentation on https://help.acumatica.com for more details.

Comment: I have found several code samples detailing how to connect using the less secure Resource Owner Password Flow, but nothing discussing how to connect using tokens other than [a code-less mention that it is possible](https://help.acumatica.com/%28W%282%29%29/Main.aspx?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=ff780860-09c2-46c9-bdd7-c6c3b1fc442c). I assumed that the lack of code meant that I should use my OIDC client of choice, but this error suggests that any client I use would fail. I have also tried looking through the SOAP client for any login methods that would allow this, but could only find User/Password.